# Partially fixed header, fixed footer, and a variable width content that is scrollable in the X and Y directions as content grows

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are lots of fixed footer/header variable width content posts but none seem to work for my specific use case.

The easiest way to describe what I want is a google doc's style interface where the header and footer are fixed and the content is X/Y scrollable but was part of the header scrolls away when you start scrolling down

https://jsfiddle.net/zve0mb5m/

```
HTML, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div {
  padding: 10px;
}

.header {
  background: LightCoral;
  border: 10px solid IndianRed;
}

.fixed-header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background: Gold;
  border: 10px solid GoldenRod;
}

.content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  background: YellowGreen;
  border: 10px solid OliveDrab;
}

.fixed-footer{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: LightSteelBlue;
  border: 10px solid SteelBlue;
  width: 100%;
}

<div class="header">
  <h1>Non fixed header content</h1>
</div>
<div class="fixed-header">
  Fixed header content
</div>
<div class="content">
  Some content that will overflow horizontally aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>
<div class="fixed-footer">
  Fixed footer content
</div>
```

The above fiddle is what I have so far, in a working solution the border for the green content section would appear just above the blue footer which would allow the horizontal scroll bar to be present.

Also, when scrolling the content section goes underneath the fixed header which isn't ideal. I want the content section to be fully visible at all times, and grow as we scroll. Possible with CSS? Do I need some JS in here?

Comment: any reason you don't use position:fixed on teh content div as well?

Comment: I need to be able to scroll initially to hide the majority of the header. How would I do that with fixed position?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the fixed items in a container `div` and use flexbox to lay them out the way you want: http://jsfiddle.net/38m5d13r/